# At what point do doubles begin to lose precision?

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754

My application needs to perform some operations: `>`, `<`, `==`, `!=`, `+`, `-`, `++`, etc. (but without division) on some numbers. Those numbers are sometimes integer, and more rarely floats.

If I use internally the "double" type (as defined by IEEE 754) even for integers, up until what point can I be safe to use them as if they were `int`s, without running in strange rounding errors (for example, `n == 5 && n == 6` are both true because they round to the same number)?

Obviously the second input of the various operations (`+`, `-`, etc.) is always an integer and I know that with `0.000[..]01` I'll have troubles since the start.

As a bonus answer, the same question but for `float`.

Comment: Please choose either `c#` or `c++` as `double` is not implemented the same between those languages.

Comment: How far to the edge of the cliff can I walk before I fall off? Why would you risk *any* loss of precision for an integer when you can simply treat them as integers? What's the rationale for wanting to use double?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to construct an example where `n == 5 && n == 6` would evaluate to `true` under any circumstances.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I am talking about bigger numbers.

Comment: @AndreasBonini: All 32-bit integers are stored exactly in a `double`, since the mantissa is > 32 bits.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: hmm quantum or n is boolean and literal ints get downgraded

Comment: @Yuck sorry to bother you after so many years, but how do doubles in `c#` differ?  Aren't they IEEE-754?

Answer (score 12):

The number of bits in a [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) double mantissa is 52, and there's an extra implied bit that is always 1. This means the maximum value that can be contained exactly is 2^53, or 9007199254740992.

A float mantissa is 23 bits, again with an implied bit. The maximum integer that can be exactly represented is 2^24, or 16777216.

If your intent is to hold integer values only, there's usually a 64-bit integer type that would be more appropriate than a double.

Edit: originally I had 2^53-1 and 2^24-1, but I realized there's no need to subtract 1 - an even number can take advantage of an implied 0 bit to the right of the mantissa.

Comment: `9007199254740992.0 == 9007199254740993.0` evaluates to true, and appears to be the first pair of integers (in the mathematical sense) that evaluate to the same number.

Comment: It's not precisely correct to say that 2^53 is the "maximum value that can be contained".  What you really mean to say is that 2^53 is the largest integer n such that every integer in the range [-n, n] can be represented exactly as a double.

Comment: @StephenCanon, thanks for the clarification. I get a little imprecise with my language sometimes. Of course larger numbers can also be exactly represented if they have zeros to the right of the mantissa, although there may be some subtleties due to rounding when you try to use it.

Comment: @Guvante how about to `0.5` of an integer since that's the maximum that the `round()` function will tolerate.

Comment: @unixman83: Do you mean a number that keeps 0.5? Such as `1.5 != 2.5`? That would be approximately 2^52 + 0.5. Playing around with a IEEE-754 calculator should get you the precise number.

Answer (score 0):

C# Refer to:
However, do be aware that the range of the decimal type is smaller than a double. That is double can hold a larger value, but it does so by losing precision. Or, as stated on MSDN:

> The decimal keyword denotes a 128-bit
>   data type. Compared to floating-point
>   types, the decimal type has a greater
>   precision and a smaller range, which
>   makes it suitable for financial and
>   monetary calculations. The approximate
>   range and precision for the decimal
>   type are shown in the following table.

The primary difference between `decimal` and `double` is that [`decimal` is fixed-point and `double` is floating point](http://floating-point-gui.de/). That means that decimal stores an exact value, while `double` represents a value represented by a fraction, and is less precise. A `decimal`is 128 bits, so it takes the double space to store. Calculations on `decimal` is also slower (measure !).

If you need even larger precision, then `BigInteger` can be used from .NET 4. (You will need to handle decimal points yourself). Here you should be aware, that BigInteger is immutable, so any arithmetic operation on it will create a new instance - if numbers are large, this might be cribbling for performance.

I suggest you look into exactly how much precision you need. Perhaps your algorithm can work with normalized values, that can be smaller ? If performance is an issue, one of the built in floating point types are likely to be faster.